# How to implement automatic printing for a website?

Tags: java, html, css, browser, printing

**Context**: Users of a web site have to print some pages (reports) generated client side (HTML/CSS). Now, they need a feature which allow them to automatically print each report.

Both browser and server (Java) can access printer.

**My options**:

**1 /** Make the browser print reports with no user action (using window.print() )

-> I don't think it's possible, a window will open and users will have to validate

**2 /** Launch a browser on the server, print the report and close the browser

-> Seems rather complicated. Is there a way to generate HTML/CSS/javascript content from Java without opening a browser ?

**3 /** Generate and print reports with Java

-> Works easily, but I'll have to generate reports both client and server side... And i'd like to avoid that. If it's the only solution, can I use my CSS while generating PDF with java ?

**Other? /** Is there another option I've not thought about ?

**FYI**: we can force users to use a specific version of a specific browser

Comment: I don't understand what a navigator is, but use write the report is generated client side. Why don't you print the page with te following javascript code: function print() {
    document.frmForm.submit(); 
    window.print(); 
} or something like that.

Comment: Ow, sorry... My english wasn't correct: I've edited my message. I meant 'browser'. window.print() will display a confirmation window, so it'll need a user action, won't it ?

Comment: Yes, user action is required

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Java servlet that does this for intranet based webapps, which it looks like you are working with given your printer reqs.

The servlet possibly could be cleaned up some, but essentially it uses [a Java library built on wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/wooio/htmltopdf-java) to parse HTML from a request body, then it does one of three things based on request options / method:

1. Downloads to client as a pdf
2. Prints the pdf content to one of the network printers
3. Pre-renders the pdf to a file on the server for later printing /
   downloading

I also recently got the printing going to allow for stapling, duplex, tray selected, etc, see `print` method:

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Media;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaTray;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import io.woo.htmltopdf.HtmlToPdf;
import io.woo.htmltopdf.HtmlToPdfException;
import io.woo.htmltopdf.HtmlToPdfObject;
import io.woo.htmltopdf.PdfPageSize;

public class PDFServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger myLog = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PDFServlet.class);
    private static final String PDF_CONTENT = "application/pdf";
    private static final String JSON_CONTENT = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    private static final String DOWNLOAD_FILE = "attachment;filename=%s.pdf";
    private static final String REQUEST_STATUS = "[{\"success\":%s}]";
    private static final String ERROR_MSG = "Error with %s request: ";

    private Map<String, File> myRenderMap = new HashMap<String, File>();
    private File myRenderDir;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

        super.init(config);
        ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletContext();
        String appRoot = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
        myRenderDir = new File(appRoot + "render");
        if (myRenderDir.exists()) 
        {
            try 
            {
                FileUtils.cleanDirectory(myRenderDir);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                myLog.error("Unable to clean render directory.", e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            myRenderDir.mkdirs();
        }
        myLog.debug("Initialized PDFServlet");

    }

    // downloads to client (or prints) a pre-rendered pdf
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException  {       

        try
        {
            String resourceId = request.getParameter("resourceId");
            String printer = request.getParameter("printer");
            String tray = request.getParameter("tray");
            String duplex = request.getParameter("duplex");
            String staple = request.getParameter("staple");

            if (resourceId == null || resourceId.equals("*") || resourceId.equals("resources"))
            {
                myLog.debug("Retrieving resources list for GET request: "
                        + request.getRequestURI()
                        + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : ""));

                response.setContentType(JSON_CONTENT);
                response.setStatus(200);
                try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
                {
                    out.println(getResources());
                }
            }
            else if (resourceId.equalsIgnoreCase("printers"))
            {
                myLog.debug("Retrieving printers list for GET request: "
                        + request.getRequestURI()
                        + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : ""));

                response.setContentType(JSON_CONTENT);
                response.setStatus(200);
                try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
                {
                    out.println(getPrinters());
                }
            }
            else if (myRenderMap.containsKey(resourceId))
            {
                myLog.debug("Retrieving pdf resource for GET request: "
                        + request.getRequestURI()
                        + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : ""));

                while (myRenderMap.containsKey(resourceId) && myRenderMap.get(resourceId) == null)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }

                File file = myRenderMap.get(resourceId);

                // print
                if (printer != null)
                {
                    myLog.debug("Printing existing resource: " + resourceId);
                    byte[] document = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
                    boolean printed = print(document, printer, resourceId, tray, duplex, staple);
                    response.setContentType(JSON_CONTENT);
                    response.setStatus(printed ? 200 : 500);
                    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
                    {
                        out.println(String.format(REQUEST_STATUS, String.valueOf(printed)));
                    }
                }

                // download
                else
                {
                    myLog.debug("Downloading existing resource: " + resourceId);
                    try (InputStream in = FileUtils.openInputStream(file)) 
                    {
                        response.setContentType(PDF_CONTENT);
                        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format(DOWNLOAD_FILE, resourceId));
                        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
                    } 
                    catch (HtmlToPdfException e) 
                    {
                        myLog.error("HTML to PDF conversion error.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                myLog.debug("Resource does not exist for GET request: "
                        + request.getRequestURI()
                        + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : ""));

                response.setContentType(JSON_CONTENT);
                response.setStatus(500);
                try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
                {
                    out.println(String.format(REQUEST_STATUS, "false"));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String msg = String.format(ERROR_MSG, "GET") 
                    + request.getRequestURI() 
                    + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : "");

            myLog.error(msg, e);
            throw new ServletException(msg, e);
        }
    }

    // downloads to client (or prints) a pdf that is created from the body content
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException  {

        myLog.debug("Retrieving pdf resource for POST request: "
                + request.getRequestURI()
                + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : ""));

        try
        {
            String resourceId = request.getParameter("resourceId");
            String size = request.getParameter("size");
            String printer = request.getParameter("printer");
            String tray = request.getParameter("tray");
            String duplex = request.getParameter("duplex");
            String staple = request.getParameter("staple");

            if (resourceId == null)
            {
                resourceId = request.getContextPath().substring(1);
            }

            // resource is currently being rendered
            if (myRenderMap.containsKey(resourceId) && myRenderMap.get(resourceId) == null)
            {
                myLog.debug("Waiting for rendering: " + resourceId);
                while (myRenderMap.containsKey(resourceId) && myRenderMap.get(resourceId) == null)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
            }

            // resource is not already rendered
            if (!myRenderMap.containsKey(resourceId))
            {
                myLog.debug("Newly rendering resource: " + resourceId);
                String[] content = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader()).split("\\|", -1);   
                HtmlToPdf html = create(content);

                html.documentTitle(resourceId);

                if (size != null)
                {
                    html.pageSize(PdfPageSize.valueOf(size));
                }
                else
                {
                    html.pageSize(PdfPageSize.Letter);
                }

                // print
                if (printer != null)
                {
                    myLog.debug("Printing new resource: " + resourceId);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    IOUtils.copy(html.convert(), baos);
                    byte[] document = baos.toByteArray();
                    boolean printed = print(document, printer, resourceId, tray, duplex, staple);
                    response.setContentType(JSON_CONTENT);
                    response.setStatus(printed ? 200 : 500);
                    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
                    {
                        out.println(String.format(REQUEST_STATUS, String.valueOf(printed)));
                    }
                }

                // download
                else
                {
                    myLog.debug("Downloading new resource: " + resourceId);
                    try (InputStream in = html.convert()) 
                    {
                        response.setContentType(PDF_CONTENT);
                        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format(DOWNLOAD_FILE, resourceId));
                        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
                    } 
                    catch (HtmlToPdfException e) 
                    {
                        myLog.error("HTML to PDF conversion error.", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            // resource is already rendered (use file)
            else
            {
                myLog.debug("Resource already exists: " + resourceId);
                File file = myRenderMap.get(resourceId);

                // print
                if (printer != null)
                {
                    myLog.debug("Printing existing resource: " + resourceId);
                    byte[] document = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
                    boolean printed = print(document, printer, resourceId, tray, duplex, staple);
                    response.setContentType(JSON_CONTENT);
                    response.setStatus(printed ? 200 : 500);
                    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
                    {
                        out.println(String.format(REQUEST_STATUS, String.valueOf(printed)));
                    }
                }

                // download
                else
                {
                    myLog.debug("Downloading existing resource: " + resourceId);
                    try (InputStream in = FileUtils.openInputStream(file)) 
                    {
                        response.setContentType(PDF_CONTENT);
                        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format(DOWNLOAD_FILE, resourceId));
                        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        myLog.error("Unable to download existing resource.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String msg = String.format(ERROR_MSG, "POST") 
                    + request.getRequestURI() 
                    + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : "");

            myLog.error(msg, e);
            throw new ServletException(msg, e);
        }
    }

    // pre-renders a pdf that is created from the body content
    @Override
    public void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException  {       

        myLog.debug("Rendering pdf resource for PUT request: "
                + request.getRequestURI()
                + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : ""));
        try
        {
            String resourceId = request.getParameter("resourceId");
            String size = request.getParameter("size");
            boolean created = false;

            if (resourceId == null)
            {
                resourceId = request.getContextPath().substring(1);
            }

            if (!myRenderMap.containsKey(resourceId))
            {
                myRenderMap.put(resourceId, null);
                String filePath = myRenderDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + resourceId + ".pdf";
                String[] content = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader()).split("\\|", -1);  
                HtmlToPdf html = create(content);

                html.documentTitle(resourceId);

                if (size != null)
                {
                    html.pageSize(PdfPageSize.valueOf(size));
                }
                else
                {
                    html.pageSize(PdfPageSize.Letter);
                }
                created = html.convert(filePath);

                if (created)
                {
                    myRenderMap.put(resourceId, new File(filePath));
                }
                else
                {
                    myRenderMap.remove(resourceId);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                while (myRenderMap.get(resourceId) == null && myRenderMap.containsKey(resourceId))
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                created = myRenderMap.containsKey(resourceId);
            }

            response.setContentType(JSON_CONTENT);
            response.setStatus(created ? 200 : 500);
            try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
            {
                out.println(String.format(REQUEST_STATUS, String.valueOf(created)));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String msg = String.format(ERROR_MSG, "PUT") 
                    + request.getRequestURI() 
                    + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : "");

            myLog.error(msg, e);
            throw new ServletException(msg, e);
        }
    }

    // removes pre-rendered pdf from server files
    @Override
    public void doDelete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException  {    

        myLog.debug("Removing pdf resource for DELETE request: "
                + request.getRequestURI()
                + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : ""));
        try
        {
            String resourceId = request.getParameter("resourceId");
            List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<String>();
            long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            for (String key : myRenderMap.keySet())
            {
                myLog.debug("Checking: " + key);
                File file = myRenderMap.get(key);
                if (file == null)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(10000); // wait 10 seconds to see if it renders
                }

                if (file == null || // the file doesn't actually exist
                    now - file.lastModified() > (1000 * 60 * 30) || // delete anything older than 30 minutes
                    key.equals(resourceId)) // requested to delete
                {
                    toRemove.add(key);
                }
            }

            myLog.debug("Removing: " + Arrays.toString(toRemove.toArray()));
            for (String key : toRemove)
            {
                myRenderMap.get(key).delete();
                myRenderMap.remove(key);
            }

            response.setContentType(JSON_CONTENT);
            response.setStatus(200);
            try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
            {
                out.println(String.format(REQUEST_STATUS, "true"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String msg = String.format(ERROR_MSG, "DELETE") 
                    + request.getRequestURI() 
                    + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : "");

            myLog.error(msg, e);
            throw new ServletException(msg, e);
        }
    }


    private HtmlToPdf create(String[] content)
    {
        HtmlToPdf html = HtmlToPdf.create();

        for (String document : content)
        {
            if (document.startsWith("<") && document.endsWith(">"))
            {
                html.object(HtmlToPdfObject.forHtml(document));
            }
            else
            {
                html.object(HtmlToPdfObject.forUrl(document));
            }
        }
        return html;
    }

    private boolean print(byte[] document, String printerIpAddress, String title, String tray, String duplex, String staple)
    {
        boolean success = false;
        List<byte[]> commands = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

        if (title != null)
        {
            commands.add(("@PJL SET JOBNAME=" + title + "\n").getBytes());
        }

        if (tray != null)
        {
            commands.add(("@PJL SET MEDIASOURCE=" + tray + "\n").getBytes());
        }

        if (staple != null)
        { 
            commands.add(("@PJL SET STAPLEOPTION=ONE\n").getBytes());
        }

        if (duplex != null)
        {
            commands.add(("@PJL SET DUPLEX=ON\n").getBytes());
            if (duplex.equalsIgnoreCase("short"))
            {
                commands.add(("@PJL SET BINDING=SHORTEDGE\n").getBytes());
            }
            else if (duplex.equalsIgnoreCase("long"))
            {
                commands.add(("@PJL SET BINDING=LONGEDGE\n").getBytes());
            }
        }

        try (Socket socket = new Socket(printerIpAddress, 9100))
        {
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            out.write(27);
            out.write("%-12345X@PJL\n".getBytes());
            for (byte[] command : commands)
            {
                out.write(command);
            }
            out.write("@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE=PDF\n".getBytes());
            out.write(document);
            out.write(27);
            out.write("%-12345X".getBytes());
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return success;
    }

    private String getResources()
    {
        List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder("[");
        long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        for (String key : myRenderMap.keySet())
        {
            File file = myRenderMap.get(key);
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (now - file.lastModified() > (1000 * 60 * 30)) // delete anything older than 30 minutes
                {
                    toRemove.add(key);
                }
                else
                {
                    json.append("{\"resourceId\":\"");
                    json.append(key);
                    json.append("\"},");
                }
            }
        }

        if (json.length() > 1)
        {
            json.setLength(json.length() - 1);
        }
        json.append("]");

        for (String key : toRemove)
        {
            myRenderMap.get(key).delete();
            myRenderMap.remove(key);
        }

        return json.toString();
    }

    private String getPrinters()
    {
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder("[");
        PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE;

        for (PrintService service : services)
        {
            json.append("{\"printer\":\"");
            json.append(service.getName());
            json.append("\",\"trays\":[");

            Object o = service.getSupportedAttributeValues(Media.class, flavor, null);
            if (o != null && o.getClass().isArray())
            {
                for (Media media : (Media[]) o)
                {
                    if (media instanceof MediaTray)
                    {
                        json.append("\"");
                        json.append(media.toString());
                        json.append("\",");
                    }
                }

                if (json.charAt(json.length() - 1) == ',')
                {
                    json.setLength(json.length() - 1);
                }
            }
            json.append("]},");
        }

        if (json.length() > 1)
        {
            json.setLength(json.length() - 1);
        }
        json.append("]");

        return json.toString();
    }
}
```